# How to Change SQLDatasource Parameter on button press

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a Gridview which is populating with entries fine.

What i need to do is enable it, so that when a string is entered within the textbox, it changes the SQLDatasource parameter to search for entries that match.

So this is the ASPx file that is being used.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="test.aspx.vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master"%>

<asp:Content ID="content" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<span class="country"></span>
<div align="right">

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox1"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" ID="Button1" OnClientClick="Button1_click" PostBackUrl="~/test.aspx" />

</div>
<br />
<br />

<div align="center">

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanel">
        <ContentTemplate>


            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="datab" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TEST] where [unit]=@unit" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Con %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Con.ProviderName %>">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="UK" Name="unit" Type="String" />

                </SelectParameters>

            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:GridView ID="View" DataSourceID="datab" runat="server" CssClass="table" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="Id">
            </asp:GridView>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The above works absolutley fine, I can change the parameter manually, and it will work. However i cannot get it to update from user submission.

Backfile:

```
Public Class test

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim unit As String = textbox1.Text

    datab.UpdateParameters("Unit").DefaultValue = unit

    updatepanel.Update()

End Sub
End Class
```

I'm guessing that i am doing something wrong when referrencing the code behind page, as the page seems to refresh when i press the button.

Any help is appreciated.

********Edit**********

I have tried to use the following code in the behind file, however it does not display anything on the actual page now.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim DS As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource
        Dim con As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\local\test.accdb"
        Dim sc As String = "SELECT * FROM [TEST] where [unit]=@unit"


    DS.ID = "datab"
    DS.ConnectionString = con
    DS.SelectCommand = sc
    DS.SelectParameters("Unit").DefaultValue = "UK"

    View.DataSource = datab
    View.DataBind()


End Sub
```

Comment: you need to `bind` `gridview` and then call update

Comment: Is that using the OnDataBinding Method? Could you explain a little more for me?

Comment: IMO you need to call view.DataSource = datab; view.DataBind();

Comment: it would be very easy if you do all of it in code behind

Comment: Therein lies an issue, it's not pulling from the Code behind so i tried to do it in the page itself.

Comment: post the code behind code and we can see that issue is solvable or not